# Google AutoML tables - sample size of an average

Tags: automl, google-cloud-automl

I'm new to google automl tables and have a basic question about which data is worthwhile including in the training of my model.

I have a dataset of golfers and will be looking at the averages of scores over different periods. For example, average over the past 3 months, 6 months, 1 year etc.

My question is, is it worthwhile also including the sample size for each date range for each player. For example, over the past 3 months, some players will have a sample size of 28 while some will only have 2. Those players that have 28 rounds will have more accurate averages than those with 2. However, I didn't know whether google automl tables would pick up this link automatically if columns are appropriately named, whether I could create a different weighting/reliability variable, or whether there's a way to specify a link between columns? Or if this automated type of automl isn't really suitable or just leave out that sample size variable?

Thanks in advance

Tried looking through documentation but haven't found anything conclusive.